# java stored procedure - resource files in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a Java stored that I load into Oracle using loadjava command. I load the entire jar file to load the classes.

Apart from class files, there are 2 resource files that get loaded in this. One of them is the jar manifest file. The other is a .properties file that I load. I use this file to control logging level in the stored procedure. I could see the resource files are loaded by selecting from USER_OBJECTS using,

```
SELECT * FROM user_objects WHERE object_type = 'JAVA RESOURCE';
```

However, I cannot see the contents, I am not a DBA, so I asked my DBA to look into the DB. He could see the object in toad, but cannot see the contents. (Funnily enough Toad doesn't even an object type "JAVA RESOURCE").

Is there any way to see the actual text in a Java resource file?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at these views

```
ALL_JAVA_ARGUMENTS
ALL_JAVA_CLASSES
ALL_JAVA_DERIVATIONS
ALL_JAVA_FIELDS
ALL_JAVA_IMPLEMENTS
ALL_JAVA_INNERS
ALL_JAVA_LAYOUTS
ALL_JAVA_METHODS
ALL_JAVA_NCOMPS
ALL_JAVA_RESOLVERS
ALL_JAVA_THROWS
ALL_SOURCE (contains the actual source code)
```

additional links:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2063.htm

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/oracle/guide8i/ch09_06.htm

Comment: Thanks for the response, Sergey. The above views are good to check on Java classes. None of those seemed to have any information on Java resources. All I wanted was to see the "contents" of the properties file I just loaded. Luckily, I found a link that talks about DBMS_JAVA package extensively, and it has a sample to display contents of various java objects using EXPORT... procedures in the package.

[link] (http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596514464/Chapters_27and28_OPLSQL5e.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The [link](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596514464/Chapters_27and28_OPLSQL5e.pdf), I posted in my comment, shows examples using procedures. Here is my anonymous block to show the contents of a resource file, based on their example:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
EXEC DBMS_JAVA.SET_OUTPUT (1000000);

DECLARE
b CLOB;
i INTEGER;
v VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(b, FALSE );
  DBMS_JAVA.EXPORT_RESOURCE('LAJavaSP.properties', b);
  i := 1000;
  DBMS_lob.read(b, i, 1, v);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v);
END;
/
```